# sprintf(target, source) has different behaviour to sprintf(target, "%s", source);

Tags: c, printf

On the C/C++ compiler that comes with a particular PlayStation platform I'm having a spot of bother with non-standard ASCII characters (used in translated languages such as Spanish - grave, acute, that sort of thing)

```
char target_string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
char string_table[][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```

if I use

```
sprintf( target_string, string_table[N] );
```

where the source string contains a character with an ascii value above 127 (ie below 0 in a signed char) the copied string includes the non-standard ascii character but no more characters from the string. The first accented European character is where the sprintf statement gives up, as if the comparison is if( char <= 0 ), finish.

if I use

```
sprintf( target_string, "%s", string_table[N] );
```

with the same string, the whole thing copies correctly, as if the comparison is if( char == 0 ) then finish.

Is this a known feature of sprintf? - ie I shouldn't use the sprintf( target, source ) version without format specifier because it's not a valid use of the function - in which case why no warnings from the compiler? Or perhaps the slightly modified compiler Sony is using is the cause. Seems unlikely.

Comment: The compiler doesn't warn because it has no way of knowing `string_table[N]` is not a valid format string.

Comment: you're absolutely right - I'm a dunce for not realising that the format string doesn't need to be a string literal, and that also there doesn't need to be a final parameter because of course the format string can be a valid string in its own right, just like with printf. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you call

```
sprintf( target_string, string_table[N] );
```

then string_table[N] will be interpreted as a "format string" (and your application will die horribly if there is a '%' in it. Don't do it)

the strange character problem is about utf-8, you should use swprintf and other wprintf-s

Comment: ahhh! I see - makes sense now. The second string effectively becomes the format string, and the third parameter (which doesn't exist) isn't a required parameter. Got it - much appreciated!

Comment: as an aside not using swprintf due to nature of Sony calls the data will end up in - would be preferred option if support existed